# Load .mat file with struct in to python arrays

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to load a .mat file (data.mat) which has been generated separately in Matlab, and load in to Python.

The data.mat file contains the struct 'Filter_Results', with multiple fields:
`Filter_Results =

struct with fields:

```
                 epoch: [7198×1 double]
                  time: [7198×2 double]
              position: [7198×3 double]
              velocity: [7198×3 double]
        position_error: [7198×3 double]
                 truth: [7198×3 double]`
```

I want to load the 'truth' variable which contains x,y,z position, in to Python.
This is my code in Python:

```
import scipy.io as spio
import numpy as np

filename1 = spio.loadmat('data.mat')
filter_results = filename1['Filter_Results']
truth = np.matrix((filter_results['truth'][:,:]))
print(truth.shape)
```

When I print truth.shape, I get a (1,1) array which isn't correct, it should be (7198,3).

Comment: what does `print(type(truth))` return? What does `print(type(filter_results['truth']))` return?

Comment: It's ok, I have solved the issue. 
I needed to add 'squeeze_me = True' to the loadmat function, then add ['truth'][()][:,:] to the penultimate line.
Thanks!